# error when importing a file from parent dir (because of an another import from the imported file)

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a project that looks like this:

```
MyProject 
├── config.py 
├── web.conf 
├── Services 
│   ├── check_db.py
```

check_db.py looks like this:

```
import sys
# add parent dir to sys.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))

from config import configuration
```

configuration class loads the web.conf.
The problem is that when I run check_db.py, there seems to be a problem to config.py to import web.conf - although they sit in the same dir (which was also added to sys.path as well).

Oh, and I am using python 3.6.

Any help with this weird issue?

Answer (score 0):

Relative imports in python - see [PEP 328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).
In your case `from ..config import configuration`